# Question about optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization, soft-question

I have a question about maximization/minimization problems.

I have noticed that for almost all the practice problems that I have had that ask to find the sum of numbers and minimize product or something along those lines, it always turns out to be that x=y=z etc.

I am wondering if there is a way to generalize this, when it is true, why it is true and how can I understand this. Is it correct?

For example, find three numbers that add to 12 and have the sum of the squares to be a minimum. Answer is x=y=z=4
Thanks

Comment: Care to post an example?

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes I added one

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this, in terms of the specific example you gave, is that both the constraint function $x+y+z$ and the objective function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ are symmetric in $x,y,z$.  That is, if you change the order of $x,y,z$, you obtain the same function.

You might like to consider the following example: find three numbers that add to $12$, such that the square of the first, plus twice the square of the second, plus three times the square of the third, is minimal.

Comment: So will having symmetric constraints always allow me to say this?

Comment: No.  For example, minimise $x^2+y^2$ subject to the constraint $x^3+y^3=1$.  The minimum is $1$, attained when either $x=1$, $y=0$ or $x=0$, $y=1$.  There is a local maximum (but not an absolute maximum) when $x=y=2^{-1/3}$.